# How to use a normal page as a dialog - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have normal page as a settings.dart :) Like this. But most of the page is empty. I want to use a smaller version of this page as a dialog. When I click the settings icon, this dialog page will pop up. How can I do it?

```
build{
return Scaffold(
body: Column(
children: <Widget>[
Text('SETTINGS')
Button
Button
Button
...
]
```

Comment: Add please more info, what tech is used , how do you use this dialog

Comment: Flutter. I dont use dialog because i dont know how to do
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html
in this link, there is a function _showMyDialog . I dont know how to call my page in this function.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://dev.to/mightytechno/flutter-alert-dialog-to-custom-dialog-1ok4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your settings button onPressed function

```
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: Dialog(
            child: settings.dartPage(),
          ),
        );
      },
```

however you need to remove the Scaffold widget in settings.dart to make it small(as the size of normal dialog) and do some customization to change it's looks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of the  `Stack` widget.

1. Wrap your `Scaffold` in an ```AnimatedOpacity`` widget and provide values of opacity and  duration.
2. Declare a global `double scaffoldOpacity = 1.0` to easily alter the opacity of the scaffold when the dialog appears and change it back when the dialog is gone.
3. Wrap the `AnimatedOpacity` widget with a `Stack` widget and then place the `SettingPage()` widget above the scaffold which is wrapped with an animated widget.
4. Wrap the `Settings()` widget in a `Visibility` widget and also provide a `bool isSettingsOpen` to toggle between the two states of the dialog.

Here is a sample snippet of the code:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  double scaffoldOpacity = 1.0;
  bool isSettingsOpen = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: scaffoldOpacity,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: FlatButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.settings),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    scaffoldOpacity = 0.3;
                    isSettingsOpen = true;
                  });
                },
              ),
              title: Text('Main Page'),
            ),
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text('MAIN PAGE BODY'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
            visible: isSettingsOpen,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Settings'),
                  //Button,

                  //Button to close settings dialog
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        scaffoldOpacity = 1.0;
                        isSettingsOpen = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),

                  // rest of the settings page ui
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```